# Change line color during a plot

Tags: gnuplot

This command draws nice green sine waves from a data file, but the col4 value goes negative periodically.

```
"" u (myDateSP(1,2)):4 lc rgb "green" lt 1 lw 6 sm cspl notitle,\
```

I'd like to have it draw the line red for negative values of col4 and green for positive values and it seems as if I should be able to use the ternary operator for that but I'm having problems with the grammar:

```
"" u (myDateSP(1,2)):4:($4<= 0) ? lc rgb "red" lt 1 lw 6 sm cspl notitle,\:lc rgb "green" lt 1 lw 6 sm cspl notitle,\
```

and other variants throw errors. Can someone point out where I have this wrong?

Your table example works nicely, many thanks.

I tried to apply it to a data file like this:

```
2015-01-03 18:02 01  29.49 feet  High Tide  
2015-01-04 01:12 01  -2.29 feet  Low Tide  
2015-01-04 07:02 01  29.09 feet  High Tide  
2015-01-04 13:22 01   4.54 feet  Low Tide  
2015-01-04 18:41 01  29.80 feet  High Tide  
2015-01-04 19:54 01   Full Moon  
2015-01-05 01:52 01  -1.87 feet  Low Tide  
2015-01-05 07:36 01  29.30 feet  High Tide  
2015-01-05 14:00 01   4.51 feet  Low Tide  
2015-01-05 19:17 01  29.99 feet  High Tide  
2015-01-06 02:26 01  -1.30 feet  Low Tide
```

and am not having much luck.

Using this:

```
set linetype 11 linecolor rgb "green"
set linetype 12 linecolor rgb "red"

set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d'
set format x '%s'

set table 'data-smoothed1.txt'
set samples 1000
plot 'data.txt' using 1:4 smooth cspline
unset table

set timefmt '%s'
set format x '%Y-%m-%d'
set xzeroaxis
plot 'data-smoothed.txt' using 1:4:($4 < 0 ? 12 : 11) linecolor variable with lines no title
```

It complains that the xrange is wrong, so when I add an range with the beginning and ending dates, it still doesn't help. The "01" column is the month number.

Comment: Concerning your edit: Please have a look at the content of the file `data-smoothed.txt`. You'll see, that it contains only two columns, so that you must use columns 1 and 2 (instead of 1 and 4) and the last line in your script must be identical to mine: `plot 'data-smoothed.txt' using 1:2:($2 < 0 ? 12 : 11) linecolor variable with lines no title`.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `linecolor variable`, which allows you to give an additional column which specifies the linecolor to use. But that doesn't work directly with `smooth`, so that you must first write the smoothed data to an external file (with gnuplot 5 you can also use a heredoc) and then plot this file with `linecolor variable`.

When doing this, you must also take care of which time format is used to write the smoothed data. The format is taken from the `set format x` settings. I would use `%s`, i.e. Unix timestamp.

Here is a full, self-contained example showing the different steps:

An example file `data.txt`:

```
2014-02-11 2
2014-03-12 -1
2014-04-15 3
2014-05-22 -2
```

And the script

```
set linetype 11 linecolor rgb "green"
set linetype 12 linecolor rgb "red"

set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d'
set format x '%s'

set table 'data-smoothed.txt'
set samples 1000
plot 'data.txt' using 1:2 smooth cspline
unset table

set timefmt '%s'
set format x '%Y-%m-%d'
set xzeroaxis
plot 'data-smoothed.txt' using 1:2:($2 < 0 ? 12 : 11) linecolor variable with lines notitle
```

[image]

Comment: From reading the GN docs and testing your reply, I can't tell if an actual column in the data file is required. Your example looks as if it should work nicely but it throws this warning warning: `extra columns ignored by smoothing option` It also plots the entire line in red.